# How to create non-editable Html Editor in ExtJs 3.4 to display some data having < , > symbols?

Tags: extjs3

I want display some data in User Interface which is inserted using Html Editor in ExtJS 3.4. The data contains < , > like symbols also. If I am displaying them in Text Area they are displayed as < , > . So I want to use Html Editor to display data instead of using TextArea. But the data should be read only. We have to made Html Editor as non editable.I have used enableSourceEdit config as false . It's not helpful for me.

Can we make Html Editor as non editable ? Would you tell me how to make it as non editable?  If you have any other solution to this problem ,would you please post here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
htmled.setReadOnly(true)
```